# Error: Cannot find module '@helpers/extenders/Message'

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, bots, node-modules

Installed open-source node js [discord bot](https://github.com/saiteja-madha/discord-js-bot).
But all of a sudden, after setting up the config, I get an error:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run start

> discord-js-bot@5.2.0 start
> node .

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@helpers/extenders/Message'
Require stack:
- D:\Programming\discord-js-bot\discord-js-bot\bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Programming\discord-js-bot\discord-js-bot\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:866:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\discord-js-bot\discord-js-bot\bot.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1191:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1245:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:904:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\Programming\\discord-js-bot\\discord-js-bot\\bot.js' ]
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It have jsconfig.json with these:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@root/*": ["./*"],
      "@handlers/*": ["./src/handlers/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
      "@schemas/*": ["./src/database/schemas/*"],
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@structures/*": ["./src/structures/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

All these files existing.

So I tried

```
npm cache clean –force
rm package-lock.json
rm -r node_modules
npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

and

`npm link package_name`

tried fully reinstall this

**none of these attempts worked.**

After all tries I get the same error that I put in beginning

Answer (score 0):

**Well..**

It helped me to add a part from jsconfig.js to package.js

```
"_moduleAliases" : {
     "@root" : ".",
     "@handlers" : "src/handlers",
     "@helpers" : "src/helpers",
     "@schemas" : "src/database/schemas",
     "@src" : "src",
     "@structures" : "src/structures"
   }
```